# No return statement in function returning non void [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// ATM menu
void Menu()
{
    cout << "          MENU           " << endl;
    cout << "1.Deposit" << endl;
    cout << "2.Balance" << endl;
    cout << "3.Withdraw" << endl;
    cout << "4.Transfer" << endl;
    cout << "5.Exit" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
}
// Tasks of ATM
int Task(int balance, int balance2, int option)
{
    int amount;
    cin >> option;
    switch(option)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "please enter the amount" << endl;
        cin >> amount;
        balance += amount;
        cout << "your balance is now:" << balance << "$" << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << balance << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "please enter the amount" << endl;
        cin >> amount;
        if(amount <= balance)
        {
            balance -= amount;
            cout << "your balance is now:" << balance << "$" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
            cout << "insufficent amount";
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "please enter the amount" << endl;
        cin >> amount;
        if(amount <= balance)
        {
            balance -= amount;
            balance2 += amount;
            cout << "your balance is now:" << balance << "$" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
            cout << "insufficent amount";
        break;
    }
}
// Main func
int main1()
{
    cout << "Please choose Your account " << endl;
    int Account1, Account2;
    cout << "Account 1   ,   Account 2" << endl;
    char x;
    cin >> x;
    int option;
    // Account 1 lines:Balance = 500 , balance 2= 700
    do
    {
        if(x == Account1)
        {
            Menu();
            cout << "option:" << endl;
            cin >> option;
            Task(500, 700, option);
        }
        // Account 2 lines : Balance = 700 , balance 2= 500
        else
        {
            int option;
            cout << "option:" << endl;
            cin >> option;
            Task(700, 500, option);
        }
    } while(option != 5);
}
```

im new to c++ and i did some coding which looks like like this and when i try to build the executable file i get this error: **no return statement in function returning non void [-Wreturn-type]** in line 40 and 64.i really have no idea what the problem is and i searched alot in the internet to understand what it is but i didn't understand the explanations at all.

Comment: Not sure what's confusing about the error message.  In `int Task(int balance,int balance2,int option)` you say `Task` will return an `int`, but nowhere in the function you do `return` an `int`.  You need to either change the return type to `void` or actually return something.

Comment: change ```int Task(...)``` to ```void Task(...)```

Answer (score 3):

It's a really simple solution. You created `int` function that never returns a value. If you have a function that you don't want any value to be returned, just make it `void`. To make your code work simply change function type from `int` to `void`

```
void Task(int balance, int balance2, int option)
```

The second issue is that you did declare balance1 and balance2, but you forgot to declare their values which lead to another error ( how is the compiler supposed to know their starting value?):

```
int Account1; Account2; // incorrect
int Account1=0, Account2=0; //fixed
```

Of course, you can also set these values later, but in this case, you should do it while declaring.

Another thing, why do you have `int main1()` function?
compiler will not treat it as you desire - it has to be called `int main()`
in order to do what you want.

Comment: There's also the mystery `int main1` function :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo i will mantion it, thank you :)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to accept answers that quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "return balance" at the end of the Task() function. You define your function to return integer, that means you have to have return statement inside the function. Also, you have to have main() function, not main1() as in your case. Every C/C++ needs function that is called main() and it represent the entry point of the program. Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// ATM menu
void Menu() {
  cout << "          MENU           " << endl;
  cout << "1.Deposit" << endl;
  cout << "2.Balance" << endl;
  cout << "3.Withdraw" << endl;
  cout << "4.Transfer" << endl;
  cout << "5.Exit" << endl;
  cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
}
// Tasks of ATM
int Task(int balance, int balance2, int option) {
  int amount;
  cin >> option;
  switch (option) {
  case 1:
    cout << "please enter the amount" << endl;
    cin >> amount;
    balance += amount;
    cout << "your balance is now:" << balance << "$" << endl;
    break;
  case 2:
    cout << balance << endl;
    break;
  case 3:
    cout << "please enter the amount" << endl;
    cin >> amount;
    if (amount <= balance) {
      balance -= amount;
      cout << "your balance is now:" << balance << "$" << endl;
      break;
    } else
      cout << "insufficent amount";
    break;
  case 4:
    cout << "please enter the amount" << endl;
    cin >> amount;
    if (amount <= balance) {
      balance -= amount;
      balance2 += amount;
      cout << "your balance is now:" << balance << "$" << endl;
      break;
    } else
      cout << "insufficent amount";
    break;
  }
  return balance;
}
// Main func
int main() {
  cout << "Please choose Your account " << endl;
  int Account1, Account2;
  cout << "Account 1   ,   Account 2" << endl;
  char x;
  cin >> x;
  int option;
  // Account 1 lines:Balance = 500 , balance 2= 700
  do {
    if (x == Account1) {
      Menu();
      cout << "option:" << endl;
      cin >> option;
      Task(500, 700, option);
    }
    // Account 2 lines : Balance = 700 , balance 2= 500
    else {
      int option;
      cout << "option:" << endl;
      cin >> option;
      Task(700, 500, option);
    }
  } while (option != 5);
}
```

Comment: its senseless to make this function int as he doesn't use this return value at all. It should be void. Plus its not intuitive which balance should it return, therefor he should stick with void.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I just said that if he says that function returns some value, that function needs a return statement.  I tried to explain how functions are used in C/C++.

Comment: Do. Or do not. There is no try.